# Why are nested tasks not canceled when they parent task is cancelled?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I need to cancel all nested tasks I try to cancel their parent but nothing happens all nested tasks keep running.

```swift
private var observationTask: Task<Void, Never>?
...
observationTask = Task {
    Task {
        for await users in list.$users.values {
            updateTableView(withUsers: users)
        }
    }
    Task {
        for await users in list.$users.values {
            updateTableView(withUsers: users)
        }
    }
}
....
observationTask.cancel()
```

}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You asked:

> Why are nested tasks not canceled when they parent task is cancelled?

Because you are using `Task`, which is for [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID643). As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye) say, it is not a subtask, but a new “top-level task”.

If you want to enjoy the benefits of structured concurrency (e.g., automatic propagation of cancelation), use task group instead of `Task { ... }`. E.g.:

```swift
let observationTask = Task {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        group.addTask {
            ...
        }
        group.addTask {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

When you `cancel` the `observationTask`, all of the task group child tasks will now be canceled for you automatically (assuming, of course, that these child tasks have been implemented to support cancelation).

For more information, see WWDC 2021 video [Explore structured concurrency in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10134/). Or see the discussion of structured vs unstructured concurrency in [The Swift Programming Language: Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642).

---

For the sake of completeness, if you want to use unstructured concurrency, you have to manually handle cancelation with [`withTaskCancellationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withtaskcancellationhandler(operation:oncancel:)/):

```swift
observationTask = Task {
    let task1 = Task {
        …
    }
    let task2 = Task {
        …
    }

    await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        _ = await task1.result
        _ = await task2.result
    } onCancel: {
        task1.cancel()
        task2.cancel()
    }
}
```

As you can see, manually handling cancelation adds some noise to our code, which is why we would generally prefer structured concurrency.

---

Please note that the above assumes that these subtasks (and possibly `updateTableView`, too) are cancelable. The fact that we do not see `try` anywhere suggests it has not implemented cancelation support (where you would `Task.checkCancellation` or test `Task.isCancelled` and manual handle the exiting of the loops if canceled).

---

To illustrate cancelation, consider:

```swift
import os.log

let log = OSSignposter(subsystem: "Test", category: .pointsOfInterest)

class Demonstration {
    private var observationTask: Task<Void, Error>?
    private let lock = NSLock()

    func start() {
        observationTask = Task {
            try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
                group.addTask { [self] in
                    for i in 0 ..< 4 {
                        try await process(i)
                    }
                }
                group.addTask { [self] in
                    for i in 200 ..< 204 {
                        try await process(i)
                    }
                }
                try await group.waitForAll()
            }
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        log.emitEvent(#function)
        
        observationTask?.cancel()
    }

    func process(_ value: Int) async throws {
        let state = lock.withLock { log.beginInterval(#function, id: log.makeSignpostID(), "\(value)") }
        defer { lock.withLock { log.endInterval(#function, state) } }

        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))   // simulate something slow and asynchronous
    }
}
```

If I do not `cancel` the `observationTask` and profile it in Instruments’s “Points of Interest” tool, I see:

[image]

But if I do `cancel` it (at the Ⓢ signpost), I see the following:

[image]

That works because:

- We used structured concurrency `withThrowingTaskGroup`; and
- The subtasks were cancelable.

Comment: I am surprised and I don't catch what different between Task and Task.detached?

Comment: I try to use your example for my case when I call observationTask.cancel() subtasks aren't canceled.

Comment: In my case I use ` try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self)` and `for try await`

Comment: Re: What's the difference between `Task` and `Task.detached`. The difference is that the former runs on the current actor, and the latter does not. But neither are structured concurrency.

Comment: Rob, thanks a lot for your expanded answer. I might have missed something while testing my code. Your code working like charm.

Comment: I meant I rewrited and retested my code and the issue gone away. Thanks.

Comment: Other than using `TaskGroup` you can use `async let` as well to take advantage of structured concurrency. If your asynchronous work doesn't follow any hierarchy to be able to be grouped, you might prefer `async let` aproach.

Comment: Agreed. The `async let` is a great alternative. But a reminder: Remember to `await` those tasks before the end of the scope of the function, because as [SE-0317](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md#implicit-async-let-awaiting) says, those tasks will be implicitly canceled when they fall out of scope. If you don’t explicitly `await` those `async let` before they fall out of scope, they will be canceled.