# Why are tasks not run concurrently on macOS 14 in SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui, task

I am having a strange problem with SwiftUI running under Sonoma in that two tasks no longer run asynchronously. I'm sure this worked before upgrading.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View 
{
    var body: some View
    {
        Button("Press me")
        {
           Task
           {
                for i in (1...5)
                {
                    print ("a", i)
                    sleep(1)
                }
            }
            Task
            {
                for i in (1...5)
                {
                    print ("b", i)
                    sleep(1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
a 5
b 1
b 2
b 3
b 4
b 5
```

or slightly strangely:

```
b 1
b 2
b 3
b 4
b 5
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
a 5
```

If I run this in a playground then everything works as expected with the output of both tasks intermingled.

As I said this did work before upgrading so what should I be doing now to do this properly?

Comment: You use the ugly thread-blocking Darwin `sleep` API. Don't. Replace `sleep(1)` with `try! await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))`

Comment: I know you know this, but for the sake of future readers, I’d be wary of `try!` because if it throws an error (e.g., if you cancel the task, it throws a `CancellationError`), the `try!` will crash your app. As a general rule, a throwing function throws for a reason and one should scrupulously avoid `try!` unless you really need/want this crashing behavior. In this case, `try await Task.sleep(…)` is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a combination of:

1. Using `Task {…}`, which creates top-level task on behalf of the current actor … since you are launching it from the main actor, you can think of it as being roughly (but not quite) analogous to GCD’s `DispatchQueue.main.async {…}`; and
2. You are using a legacy `sleep` function which blocks the calling thread, thereby temporarily blocking the actor (again, the main actor).

So, the combination of these two effects is that you have two blocking tasks, both running on the main actor, so one will block the other (to say nothing about blocking the main actor altogether, which is a very bad idea).

---

So, the question is what was your intent with `sleep(1)`: If it was intended as a placeholder for some `async` function, then we would use `Task.sleep` instead, which is a better proxy for `async` functions. Unlike traditional `sleep` functions, the `Task.sleep` does *not* block the current thread/actor. And because of [actor reentrancy](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md#actor-reentrancy), as soon as you hit the `await` suspension point in one loop, the other task is free to run.

Consider:

```swift
import os.log

let logger = Logger(subsystem: "Test", category: "ContentView")

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Press me") {
            Task {
                for i in 1...5 {
                    logger.debug("a \(i)")
                    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                }
            }
            Task {
                for i in 1...5 {
                    logger.debug("b \(i)")
                    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

That manifests the concurrent/asynchronous behavior you were looking for because we avoided using the legacy blocking API (e.g., `sleep`):

```
b 1
a 2
b 2
a 3
b 3
a 4
b 4
b 5
a 5
```

---

On the other hand, if your intent with `sleep(1)` was as a placeholder for some slow, computationally intensive, synchronous function, we would want to make sure to get this off the current actor. We could use a detached task, putting it in a nonisolated `async` function, a task group, etc.

For example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Press me") {
            Task.detached {
                for i in 1...5 {
                    logger.debug("a \(i)")
                    …
                }
            }
            Task.detached {
                for i in 1...5 {
                    logger.debug("b \(i)")
                    …
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Note, if you really are performing some slow, computationally intensive calculation then you probably should periodically `Task.yield` within that process, or move it outside the Swift concurrency system. But all of this is probably beyond the scope of the question.

---

Bottom line, this behavior is unrelated to your macOS version. It is the result of the combination of tasks added to the main actor which are blocking the current thread. To solve the problem, either move to asynchronous API or get it off the current actor.

Answer (score 2):

1. In SwiftUI it is `.task` not `Task {}`.
2. To pause it is `Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))` not `sleep(1)`.
3. To have 2 nested tasks but still support cancellation you need to use `TaskGroup`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73983517/259521) for more info.

Doing all that should look something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var isRunning = false

    var body: some View
    {
        Button("\(isRunning ? "Stop" : "Start")")
        {
            isRunning.toggle()
        }
        .task(id: isRunning) { // runs on appear and cancelled and restarted when id changes.
            if(!isRunning){
                return
            }
            await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
                group.addTask {
                    for i in (1...5)
                    {
                        print ("a", i)
                        do {
                            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                        }
                        catch {
                            break // cancelled
                        }
                    }
                }
                group.addTask {
                    
                    for i in (1...5)
                    {
                        print ("b", i)
                        do {
                            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                        }
                        catch {
                            break // cancelled
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            isRunning = false
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
b 1
a 1
b 2
a 2
a 3
b 3
b 4
a 4
b 5
a 5
```

Don't ask me why `b` is first!